I've been facing an error, I can't update or upgrade or perform package installs on my system because of the following errors:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]


The PPA you have installed does not support Jammy - see here.

https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu repo don't support jammy. Try open link in browser and look under 'dists'
